# Horizontal three button set in inner view using autolayout programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I don't have good knowledge of autolayout please help me, 
Here i attach a image in red color near on "In" (right side red view) i have add Three Horizontal button according to text i want to set button ("#test" , "#general" , "#Banter") But the problem is so spacing between then buttons AND when name is big my code is not working properly

```
 var setxPosition:CGFloat = 0
                var getwidth:CGFloat = cell.viewChannel!.frame.size.width
                var setxPosition2:CGFloat = getwidth/3
                setxPosition = -setxPosition2

                for object in cell.viewChannel!.subviews
                {

                    object.removeFromSuperview();
                }
                for var i = 0; i < getChannelname.count; i++ {

                        setxPosition = setxPosition + setxPosition2
                        var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
                        button.frame = CGRectMake(setxPosition, 0, 100, 30)
                        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                        button.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                        button.setTitle("#\(getChannelname[i])" , forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)


                        button.addTarget(self, action: "gotoChannel_byChannel:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
                        cell.viewChannel!.addSubview(button)

                }
```

[image]

Need a solution like this

```
NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[Button1(Button2)]-5-[Button2]-10-|"
                                                                             options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views];
```